# Error Divisão por 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá

Gostaria de uma ajuda, estou iniciando com a linguagem e estou tento algumas duvidas, O que eu quero no meu código é que o calculo da divisão não seja divido por zero. No momento que eu insiro o valor de Y = 0 retorne uma mensagem "Invalido, não pode ser divido por 0".

Quando eu faço um insert com o divisor 0 retorna essa mensagem:

```
Calculadora03.rb:32:in `/': divided by 0 (ZeroDivisionError)
        from Calculadora03.rb:32:in `calculo'
        from Calculadora03.rb:57:in `<main>'
```

Esse é o meu codigo:

```
def escolha_operador
    puts "Escolha o tipo de operação abaixo:"
    puts "1 Adição"
    puts "2 Subtração"
    puts "3 Multiplicação"
    puts "4 Divisão"
    puts ""

    tipo_operador = gets.chomp().to_i

    if tipo_operador == 1
        return "Adição"
    elsif tipo_operador == 2
        return "Subtração"
    elsif tipo_operador == 3
        return "Multiplicação"
    elsif tipo_operador == 4
        return "Divisão"
    else
        return "erro"
    end
end

def calculo(operacao, x, y)
    if operacao == "Adição"
        return resultado = x + y
    elsif operacao == "Subtração"
        return resultado = x - y
    elsif operacao == "Multiplicação"
        return resultado = x * y
    elsif operacao == "Divisão"
        return resultado = x / y
    end
  # elsif operacao == "Divisão"
    #   rescue ZeroDivisionError
    #   else
    #   return resultado = x / y
  # end
end

continuar = 1

while continuar == 1

  calculo_atual = escolha_operador()

  if calculo_atual == "erro"

    puts "Opção invalido! Escolha a opção correta."

    else
    puts "Entre com o primeiro valor da #{calculo_atual}: "
    p_numero = gets.to_i
    puts "Entre com o segundo valor da #{calculo_atual}: "
    s_numero = gets.to_i

    result = calculo(calculo_atual, p_numero, s_numero)

    puts "O resultado é #{result}"
    puts "Deseja continuar o calculo? Digite 1- Sim ou 2- Não"
    continuar = gets.to_i

        system ('cls')

    if continuar != 1


    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Você quer subverter a matemática? Qual seria o resultado de um número dividido por 0?

Comment: A sua pergunta não é clara. Dividir por 0 é um erro que foi descoberto muito antes da invenção das linguagens de programação. Agora, se vc deseja tratar a divisão quando o divisor for 0, basta fazer um `if` antes invocar a divisão. Caso o divisor seja 0, não divida

Comment: @Amadeus desculpe eu acabei descrevendo errado mesmo a minha duvida. O que eu quero no meu código é que o calculo da divisão nao seja divido por zero. No momento que eu esteja colocando o valor de Y = 0 retorne uma mensagem "Invalido, não pode ser divido por 0".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como o Isaque disse, coloque uma IF para o `y`, deve ficar assim:

```
elsif operacao == "Divisão"
    if y != 0
        return resultado = x / y
    else
        return "Invalido, não pode ser divido por 0"
    end
end
```

Então isto:

```
result = calculo(calculo_atual, p_numero, s_numero)

puts "O resultado é #{result}"
```

Vai exibir algo como:

> O resultado é Invalido, não pode ser divido por 0

Answer (score 1):

É uma regra da matemática, nada pode ser dividido por 0.
Em qualquer linguagem de programação irá dar erro se tentar dividir por 0.
Você pode botar um `if` para verificar se o divisor não é `0`.

Comment: Comentei errado hehe, eu nao quero que no meu código, o calculo da divisão seja divido por 0.

Comment: @Cintia e tentou colocar a IF para verificar se o divisor é 0 como o Isaque disse?

Comment: sim @GuilhermeNascimento coloquei. Deu certo

Comment: @Cintia **que erro?** O mesmo? Se foi o mesmo é porque não fez a IF de maneira correta, mostra como você colocou essa if. Veja se assim funciona: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/239444/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu só editei a minha duvida... mas fiz conforme vc disse ...usei o IF e deu certo

Comment: @Cintia legal, se deu certo marque a minha resposta ou a do Isaque como correta (a que vc preferir)

Answer (score 1):

Divisões por zero lançam uma exceção do tipo `ZeroDivisionError`, que pode capturada com `raise` e traduzida para um `Float::NaN` (*Not A Number*), veja só:

```
def calculo(operacao, x, y)
    if operacao == "Adição"
        return resultado = x + y
    elsif operacao == "Subtração"
        return resultado = x - y
    elsif operacao == "Multiplicação"
        return resultado = x * y
    elsif operacao == "Divisão"
        return resultado = x / y
    end
rescue ZeroDivisionError
    return Float::NAN
end

p calculo("Divisão", 1, 0 )
p calculo("Divisão", 10, 2 )
p calculo("Divisão", 70, 5 )
p calculo("Divisão", 20, -5 )
```

Saída:

```
NaN
5
14
-4
```

Exemplo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/M3Pa)

Comment: na época tentei usar esse comando rescue, e não estava dando certo.. obrigado pela ajuda...

Answer (score 0):

Altera o pedaço de código para isto:

```
def calculo(operacao, x, y)
if operacao == "Adição"
    return resultado = x + y
elsif operacao == "Subtração"
    return resultado = x - y
elsif operacao == "Multiplicação"
    return resultado = x * y
elsif operacao == "Divisão"
    if y != 0
       return resultado = x / y
    end
end
```

O problema é que não se pode dividir um número por zero. É uma regra matemática.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme comentários acima, a regra matemática impossibilita a divisão por 0.

Assim caso você queira tentar dividir mesmo assim algum numero por 0, poderia tentar a solução

```
10.try(:/, 0)
```

onde obterá a resposta:
ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0.

Contudo lembrando que a boa prática deveria ser verificar o valor antes de tentar tal operação.